# Matplotlib cannot create consistent method ordering in python (vscode)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

**I'm trying to import and run matplotlib in python but I get a error message:**

[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJMG4.png)

---

**The version I'm running are:**

Python 3.10.4
matplotlib 3.5.2
virtualenv 20.14.1

(I'm using a virtualenv)

---

**My code:**

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))
```

---

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question and my formatting was incorrect

Comment: Please don't use images of code or errors when these are just text. Copy-paste the error message into your question, then format it as code.

Comment: See also https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/361